# no consigo mi crud haga el /save

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estoy haciendo un crud sencillo con springboot y thymeleaf pero al hacer el save del update y del create pierdo los datos del objeto y no consigo saber en donde. Hago click en los botones new y update me abre correctamente el modal con los datos bien recogidos en el caso del update pero al salvar no me funciona bien el save.

**yo creo que mi problema está en el formulario y no sé cuál es. he probado con postman y no recibo request al hacer el click en save de save or update**

index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Paginación con SpringBoot</h1>
    </div>  
    <button class="btn btn-success nBtn">New</button>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>COUNTRY</th>
                        <th>CAPITAL</th>
                        <th>ACTION</th>
                    </tr>   
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="country :${data.content}">
                        <td th:text="${country.id}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${country.name}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${country.capital}"></td>
                        <td>
                            <a th:href="@{/delete/(id=${country.id})}" class="btn btn-danger dBtn">Delete</a>
                            <a th:href="@{/findOne/(id=${country.id})}" class="btn btn-primary eBtn">Edit</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills  nav-justified">
                <li class="nav-item" th:each="i :${#numbers.sequence(0,data.totalPages-1)}">
                    <a th:href="@{/(page=${i})}" th:text="${i}" class="nav-link" th:classappend="${currentPage}==${i}?'active':''"></a>
                </li>   
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="myForm">
     <form th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${country}" method="post">
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update or Create</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id" class="col-form-label">Id:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" th:value="*{''}" disabled/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" th:value="*{''}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="capital" class="col-form-label">Capital:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="capital" name="capital" th:value="*{''}"/>
                  </div>                      
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Save"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <p class="alert alert-danger">Are you sure you want to delete this?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger" id="delRef">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller :

```
        @Controller
public class CountryController {

@Autowired
private CountryRepository countryRepository;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@GetMapping("/")
public String showPage(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue="0") int page) {
    model.addAttribute("data", countryRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page,4)));
    model.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
    return "index";
}

@PostMapping("/save")
public String save(Country country) {
    countryRepository.save(country);
    return "redirect:/";
}

@GetMapping("/delete")
public String deleteCountry(Integer id) {
    countryRepository.deleteById(id);;
    return "redirect:/";
}

@GetMapping("/findOne")
@ResponseBody
public Optional<Country> FindOne(Integer id) {
    return  countryRepository.findById(id);


}
```

}

mi js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.nBtn, .table .eBtn').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var text = $(this).text();

    if(text=='Edit'){
        $.get(href,function(country,status){
            $('.myForm #id').val(country.id);
            $('.myForm #name').val(country.name);
            $('.myForm #capital').val(country.capital);
        });

        $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();
    }else{
        $('.myForm #id').val('');
        $('.myForm #name').val('');
        $('.myForm #capital').val('');
        $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();
    }
});
$('.table .dBtn').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#myModal #delRef').attr('href',href);
    $('#myModal').modal();
});});
```

class:

```
@Entity
public class Country {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String capital;


    public Country(String name, String capital) {
        this.name = name;
        this.capital = capital;
    }

    public Country() {
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", capital=" + capital + "]";
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCapital() {
        return capital;
    }
    public void setCapital(String capital) {
        this.capital = capital;
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías probar si tu API funciona correctamente utilizando un REST client como Postman. Adicional...en el navegador has visto si está saliendo el request hacía tu servidor? Cúal es la respuesta que estás obteniendo del request?

Comment: si, creo que me problema es que no me sale nada hacia el servidor y no se porque es